# Prevent cell from being created

Tags: iphone, ios, object, uitableview

In a tableview, I need to prevent a cell from being created by a given condition.

For example, I have a tableview that shows a couple of results but I want the app to filter them. Is a way to do this?

Best Regards.

Comment: why would you want to prevent a cell from being created ? instead, return the right number of rows, given that condition. the cell won't be created

Comment: maybe he wants to filter the content inside the table, if it's what he want, try reloading the table on each occasion, or add an exception in the tableview cell method so that if the condition are not met, the cell proceed to populate with the next data possible

Comment: I suggest you read up on "Model View Controller"

Comment: @YonathanJm The tableview should not be responsible for filtering or adding exceptions to. The tableview should just display all of the data that is given to it. If you want to filter the data that is displayed, then you filter the data in your model and then give the tableview the data to display.

Comment: @NickBull come to think of it, you're probably right, after all if the data that were prepared to populate the tableview got skipped, an error might happened considering the number of data that are returned doesn't match the data provided. in that case he should be best of by using reload method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preventing a cell from being created doesn't sound good. The simplest way to do that is to implement correctly the `...numberOfRowsInSection:` method given the condition :

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(condition) {
        return theNumberOfRowsGivenTheCondition;
    }
    else {
        return someOtherRowsCount;
    }
}
```